# pip install django-allauth UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, pip, ubuntu-10.04, docker

I'm trying to pip install django-allauth with Python 3.3.2 in a docker container and I'm getting a Unicode Decode Error. https://dpaste.de/JaXg It installs properly on my mac... Any ideas?

Running Vagrant with Docker inside. Vagrant is running precise and my docker container is xdrum/ubuntu10.04-base from this docker index (https://index.docker.io/u/xdrum/ubuntu10.04-base/). Doing a pip install from a virtual env inside the docker container. Pip version 1.4.1 and python 3.3.2.

On my mac, django-allauth installs just fine in an os x virtual environment.

Really sturggling to figure this one out, so thanks for the help!!!

Comment: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/475

Comment: Hey, out of curiosity, why do you use Ubuntu 10.04 rather than 12.04? I understand that you would go for a LTS version (I do the same), but 10.04, whoa :-) It looks like [this commit](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/f55961063f5b0114ef8030c06430929007ecfb29) addresses the issue; can you try again, and if it doesn't work, post a link to a Dockerfile showing how to reproduce?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 10.04 to mimic a heroku box as that's what they are running. New push had another UnicodeDecodeError for me, but made a pull request to encode to ascii which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a LOCALE? There isn't one defined by default in the Docker container. In most cases you don't even have to install the locale packages, just define the LOCALE environment variable.

(ps your snippet isn't available on dpaste.de anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up locale helps

```
RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
```